# How to add line number by resetting it after each common pattern?

Tags: bash

I have a file that looks like this:

```
dddd  
3434  
5445  
5656  
2323  
dddd  
67  
565  
454  
dddd  
45  
56  
78
```

I want to add line numbers to this file by setting the numbers again after each pattern 'dddd'. An output like this:

```
dddd  
1 3434  
2 5445  
3 5656  
4 2323  
dddd  
1 67  
2 565  
3 454  
dddd  
1 45  
2 56  
3 78
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: We do encourage all users to add their efforts in their post which they have put in order to solve their own problems, kindly do add the same in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
awk '/dddd/ { ln = 1; print; next } { print ln++, $0 }' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a script like this, the dirty way. It takes the path of the file to be parsed as the first argument

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && { exit; }
IFS="
"
C=1
PATTERN=dddd
for LINE in `<"$1"`;do
    [[ "$LINE" =~ $PATTERN ]] && {
        let C=1
        echo $LINE
        continue
    }
    echo "$C $LINE"
    let C=$C+1
done
```

Comment: In bash `\`cat file\`` is the same as `$(<file)`, so you don't need `cat` there. And `echo $LINE | grep $PATTERN &> /dev/null; [ "$?" == "0" ]` is the same as `grep -q "$PATTERN" <<<"$LINE"` or even better `[[ "$LINE" =~ $PATTERN ]]`.

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail, I cleaned the code following your advices